# Expresion para acción de un indicador de report viewer para que se accione cuando un cadena concuerde con la de el dataset nombre de una columna

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Bueno  tengo un report viewer  en la  cual   tengo un  indicador  que indica  cuando la celda de la  columna resultado1 esta en el rango de  2 a 3.8 indica  con una ▲ cuando resultado1 es de 3.9 a 5.9 indica ▬ y cuando la  celda  de resultado1 es de 5.9-7 indica ▼ hasta  halla  todo bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Report viewer en ejecución**

[image: reportvier en ejeccucion]

ahora bien como son varias filas que aparecerán yo quiero que  cuando en la celda de la columna prueba sea igual a "Eritrocitos" se accione  ese indicador  y no para Hemoglobina (Hb)y Hematocrito (Hto) ya  que estos  ocupan otro indicador  con otros  rangos

He intendado yendo a **propiedades del indicador** en **acción**  en **ir a informe** poniendo esta  expresion

```
=First(Fields!nomprueba.Value, "DtsResultados").Equals("Eritrocitos")
```

tambien intentecon esta

```
=Fields!nomprueba.Value.Equals("Eritrocitos")
```

tambien intentecon esta

```
=First(Fields!nomprueba.Value, "DtsResultados") Like "Eritrocitos"
```

y no  funciona ninguna les agradeceria  si me pueden ayudar